# Server configuration notation

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, central-processing-unit, memory

What is the industry standard to specify Virtual machine configuration in a summary format?

I have seen notations like these:

```
4 CPU x 8 GB RAM VM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it an industry standard ?

No, there is no standard and no best way. This is off-topic here, please read the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: can you link to the rule?

Comment: @TomH Oh, I wasn't aware that the tag autolinking isn't working in answers, just in comments.

Comment: I guess I meant is that off topic because it is a "learning material recommendation", or that it is chatty/discursive?

Comment: I think chatty/discursive nails it. It's also not an actual problem per se, IMHO.

Comment: what about if it was reframed as "What is the industry standard to specify Virtual machine configuration in a summary format?". I guess my point is you could get into a discussion about almost anything, but there are only a few major VM players, and cloud providers, and if they have standardized around something, then there is a specific answer to the question.

Comment: I think it would be interesting in the context of a standard for programmatic descriptions of VM's, especially in the context of cross-vendor vm migration and service catalog population but otherwise it is more of an exercise in marketing interpretation